# Javascript group by array of objects (complicated objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

After a lot of tries and search, I couldn't solve my following problem:
I have the following array

```
[
{text: "text", title: "title", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [
  {title: "subTitle", text: "subText", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"123", title:"321"}, 
    {text:"456", title:"654"},
    {text:"789", title:"765"}
  ]},
   {title: "subTitle", text: "subText2", cid: "cid2", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle1"}, 
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle2"},
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle3"}
  ]},
  {title: "subTitle", text: "subText3", cid: "cid3", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"ycycy", title:"asd"}, 
    {text:"nyd", title:"yf"},
    {text:"xfg", title:"qq"}
  ]},
  {title: "anotherSubTitle", text: "subText4", cid: "cid4", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"fff", title:"hhh"}, 
    {text:"xxx", title:"sss"},
    {text:"hhh", title:"jjj"}
  ]}
]}
]
```

I want to reach the following format:

```
[
{text: "text", title: "title", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [
  {title: "subTitle", text: "subText", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"123", title:"321"}, 
    {text:"456", title:"654"},
    {text:"789", title:"765"},
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle1"},
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle1"},
    {text:"testText", title:"testTitle1"},
    {text:"ycycy", title:"asd"}, 
    {text:"nyd", title:"yf"},
    {text:"xfg", title:"qq"}
  ]},
  {title: "anotherSubTitle", text: "subText4", cid: "cid4", active: true, nodes: [
    {text:"fff", title:"hhh"}, 
    {text:"xxx", title:"sss"},
    {text:"hhh", title:"jjj"}
  ]}
]}
]
```

I tried **array.reduce** and to loop through the array but each time I got a wrong result...
Any suggestion plz?

Comment: Can you include the reducer you tried?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any "grouping" going on in the traditional sense. Just moving all of the elements in the `nodes` array of the second level elements into the first element's `nodes` array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge/concatenate values of same object properties in an array of objects using lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025657/how-to-merge-concatenate-values-of-same-object-properties-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Unfortunately no answer could help... Actually I am trying to group by `text` in the nodes in the first level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a nested grouping by a property for all levels.

```js
const
    groupBy = (array, key) => array.reduce((r, { nodes, ...o }) => {
        let temp = r.find(q => q[key] === o[key]);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = o);
        if (nodes) (temp.nodes ??= []).push(...groupBy(nodes, key));
        return r;
    }, []),
    data = [{ text: "text", title: "title", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [{ title: "subTitle", text: "subText", cid: "cid", active: true, nodes: [{ text: "123", title: "321" }, { text: "456", title: "654" }, { text: "789", title: "765" }] }, { title: "subTitle", text: "subText2", cid: "cid2", active: true, nodes: [{ text: "testText", title: "testTitle1" }, { text: "testText", title: "testTitle2" }, { text: "testText", title: "testTitle3" }] }, { title: "subTitle", text: "subText3", cid: "cid3", active: true, nodes: [{ text: "ycycy", title: "asd" }, { text: "nyd", title: "yf" }, { text: "xfg", title: "qq" }] }] }],
    result = groupBy(data, 'title');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```